# Advanced Windows volume mixer

Tags: windows, audio, volume-control

I have three different sound output devices, a TV, USB speakers and USB headphones wired in.

When I'm playing a movie on my TV with sound, I would like to be able to start an application and have the sound come out of my headphones.

Is there an application that lets you match a program with a sound output device? No matter how many programs and out put devices you have?

Comment: still looking ! That would help me a great deal

Comment: google audio router I realize how old this post is old but it took me years to find it as well. best solution i have for it anyway